# Connection String error on remote server

Tags: iis, asp-classic

when i use this connection string it works locally but when i upload my website unto my webserver remotely it gives me an error saying

HTTP/1.1 New Application Failed

this is my connection string

```
<%
' FileName="Connection_ado_conn_string.htm"
' Type="ADO" 
' DesigntimeType="ADO"
' HTTP="true"
' Catalog=""
' Schema=""
Dim MM_advtours_STRING
MM_advtours_STRING = "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=" &Server.MapPath("/mysite.com/mysite.mdb")
%>
```

please i want to know what is wrong-

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your domain is mysite.com and your database is mysite.mdb located in the root of the site. If so, try Server.MapPath("/mysite.mdb")